# SELECT syntax in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

For the following snippet of code:

```
select @total = count(*) from (...)
```

What does it do? Does it return a table?

If I do something like:

```
select * from (select @total = count(*) from (...))
```

Why is there syntax error around '='?

Comment: It sets the value for the variable `@total`

Comment: you cannot assign data to variable total and select it in one statement. I think you are trying to achieve `SELECT count(*) AS 'total' from table`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT @total = COUNT(*) FROM (...)
```

In the example you've given (above) `SELECT` is equivalent to `SET`.  It is setting the `@total` variable to the result of the count query.

You can use `SELECT` to assign values to more than one variable in a single statement, whereas `SET` can only do 1 at a time.

For example, this:

```
SELECT @Abc = 123, @Def = 456
```

Is equivalent to this:

```
SET @Abc = 123
SET @Def = 456
```

[Here](http://vyaskn.tripod.com/differences_between_set_and_select.htm)'s quite a good article that goes into more detail about the differences.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT @total = COUNT(*) FROM ...
```

does not return *anything*.  It just *sets* the value of the variable `@total`.  That's why you can't use it as a sub-query - because it does not return a result set.